# TortoiseGit IBugTraqProvider2 interface

Tags: tortoisegit

I'm using TortoiseGit 2.10.0.2.  I wrote an Issue Tracker plugin based on the sample programs in C#.  Everything works OK except for configuration.  On the Setup Issue Tracker Config screen, there is a field called "Provider parameters" where I can manually enter a configuration string.  Appendix B of the manual describes the HasOptions and ShowOptionsDialog interfaces for entering the parameters with a GUI instead of a raw string.  The appendix says this interface is called when the user clicks the "Options" button.  However, there is no "Options" button on the Issue Tracker Config screen.

If I use the Issue Tracker Integration screen to add my plugin to a specific Git directory, the "Options" button is present and works.  But I don't want to have to set this up every time a repository is cloned.

How to I get the "Options" button to show on the Setup Issue Tracker Config screen?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the provider UUID and the params to `.tgitconfig` (i.e., called "project" on the settings page; the config keys are name `bugtraq.provideruuid`, `bugtraq.provideruuid64` and `bugtraq.providerparams`). Then you can commit this file and the settings are always used.

There is, however, no "Options" button available there - the values need to be entered manually.

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-hooks-issuetracker-config

Comment: @n8zrj Please consider to accept this answer if it helped you or leave a comment on what's still missing.